# How can I emulate ErrorProvider in .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: data-binding, compact-framework, errorprovider

Since there is no ErrorProvider class in .NETCF, how can I implement similar functionality (not necessarily *exactly* like ErrorProvider)?

I am using all the regular databinding constructs to bind controls to a datatable, using the DataRow.RowError property and DataRow.SetColumnError method, but I can't find events on any of DataTable, BindingManagerBase, etc. that I can hook into to receive any sort of notification.

Am I stuck calling a method to manually iterate through all the controls on my form and change some look/feel of the bound control?

Thanks,
MrB

Answer (score 0):

The `ErrorProvider` class seems pretty basic - actually, a little too basic. If you have [Red Gate Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), I would recommend disassembling the class and looking at it. Otherwise, create a `Dictionary<Control, String>`.

Here is a quick idea on creating your own provider:

```
Dictionary<Control, String> ErrorSet = new Dictionary<Control, String>();

public void SetError(Control control, String message)
{
    // code for adding error information
    ErrorSet.Add(control, message);
}

public String GetError(Control control)
{
    // code for retrieving error information
    return ErrorSet[control];
}

public String Clear()
{
    // code for clearing all errors
}
```

I don't have R-G reflector here or I would provide more sample methods. But this ought to provide some sort of sample to work from.